# PHP passing params to new string (learning)

Tags: javascript, php

Still learning and still many questions so here a few go. I am doing a javascript -> PHP conversion and want to make sure these practices are correct. Is $dailyparams->$calories = $calories; a correct line? Thanks again!

JAVASCRIPT

```
DailyParams.create4 = function(/*double*/ calories, /*double*/ carbpercent, /*double*/ sodium, /*double*/ actparam) {
if (calories < 0.0) calories = 0.0;
if (carbpercent < 0.0) carbpercent = 0.0;
if (carbpercent > 100.0) carbpercent = 100.0;
if (sodium < 0.0) sodium = 0.0;
if (actparam < 0.0) actparam = 0.0;

var dailyparams = new DailyParams();
dailyparams.calories = calories;
dailyparams.carbpercent = carbpercent;
dailyparams.sodium = sodium;
dailyparams.actparam = actparam;

return dailyparams;}
DailyParams.create2 = function(/*Intervention*/ inter, /*Baseline*/ base) {
var dailyparams = new DailyParams();
dailyparams.calories = inter.getcalories();
dailyparams.carbpercent = inter.getcarbinpercent();
dailyparams.sodium = inter.getsodium();
dailyparams.actparam = inter.getAct(base);

return dailyparams;
```

}

PHP

```
public function create4($calories, $carbpercent, $sodium, $actparam) {
    if ($calories < 0.0) $calories = 0.0;
    if ($carbpercent < 0.0) $carbpercent = 0.0;
    if ($carbpercent > 100.0) $carbpercent = 0.0;
    if ($sodium < 0.0) $sodium = 0.0;
    if ($actparam < 0.0) $actparam = 0.0;

    $dailyparams = new $DailyParams();
    $dailyparams->$calories = $calories;
    $dailyparams->$carbpercent = $carbpercent;
    $dailyparams->$sodium = $sodium;
    $dailyparams->$actparam = $actparam;

    return $dailyparams;
}
public function create2($inter,$base) {
    $dailyparams = new $DailyParams();
    $dailyparams->$calories = $inter->getcalories();
    $dailyparams->$carbpercent = $inter->getcarbinpercent();
    $dailyparams->$sodium = $inter->getsodium();
    $dailyparams->$actparam = $inter->getAct($base);

    return $dailyparams;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DailyParams` is a classname, lose the `$`:

```
$dailyparams = new DailyParams();
```

Same with property names like `calories`:

```
$dailyparams->calories = $calories;
```

Comment: ah yes I thought something looked funny there - thanks! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Those are the things that are incorrect and keep it from working.  Everything else looks OK.